# Bluetooth mouse vs 2x computers

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, razer-mouse

I have a Bluetooth mouse (Razer Orochi), and I regularly switch between two computers which I'd like to use it with. Is there a way to make it so that I don't have to re-pair it every single time I change from one to the other?

Comment: Then how would the mouse know which computer it is connected to at that moment?

Comment: @Soandos: not my problem ^^

Comment: I read what you are asking. I am telling you why its needed. The mouse cannot be connected to two computers at a time. The way it connects it by pairing. The reason that it has to pair is so that it knows how to communicate with the device. I supposed that it might be possible to hash something out over a PAN but it would be a very bad idea as all commands would be sent to both computers.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Microsoft Bluetooth 5000 Mouse. Windows offers a 'Software-managed Bluetooth mode' in Bluetooth settings, but I can't find an equivalent way to do this in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The "old-fashioned" way of using a KVM is one. Essentially it's a box that you plug your devices into. Flip the switch on it to switch computers. There are other features provided (more than 2 computers, more than 2 in/outputs, buttons, yadda yadda yadda not relevant) but that's basically it.

You can also use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), where basically you just move your mouse between screens to change both the "focus" of the keyboard and monitor. It works by pairing the device with a "host" computer then having it essentially pass off the input commands to the other computer when the mouse changes monitors.

Comment: The problem with a KVM switch is with the OS. When you switch from one computer to the other, the first one loose the BT connectivity. So when you come back, the OS has to find the mouse / keyboard again and there is a lag that can take upon 10 seconds (using myself a Belkin Soho 4 ports KVM). That can make the deal, but it's very frustating having to wait looong seconds before being able to do something after each switch.

Comment: This depends on the KVM switch. There is no reason why a good switch has any lag for any input or output. In > 2010 it is a shame that people (including engineers in KVM producing companies) think a switch for devices should be just physical disconnect and switch.

Look what the high end switches can do today (the 1500 Euro and up price tag), it's mind blowing.

Answer (score 6):

ok a stupid solution I use is to disable any onboard bluetooth and use a dongle. Plug it into computer 1 - mouse and keyboard work on computer one - take it out and plug it into computer 2 - mouse and keyboard work on computer two.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/)

> Synergy is
>   Software that lets you easily share
>   your mouse and keyboard between
>   multiple computers, where each
>   computer has it's own display. No
>   special hardware is required, all you
>   need is a local area network. Synergy
>   is supported on Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux. Redirecting the mouse and
>   keyboard is as simple as moving the
>   mouse off the edge of your screen.

Comment: Synergy actually isn't free anymore.

Comment: @PimBrouwers yes, pre-compiled builds are now paid but you should be able to download and build from source https://github.com/symless/synergy https://symless.com/purchase/faq/

Comment: Watch LinusTechTips on Youtube and find the many with special offers and catch one of them and support the project. It needs support.

Answer (score 2):

I have not had direct experience with this product ...

[Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse T630](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/ultrathin-touch-mouse-t630?crid=7)

but I do own it's sister product for keyboards ...

[Logitech Bluetooth Illuminated Keyboard K810](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810?crid=26)

I like this solution because is works with PC, Mac, iOS, and Android. I use an iPad at work that is not connected to my LAN. It uses cellular for data. I also have my MacBook Pro which is also connected to a different network. Then my development PC which is on the company network. I can easily switch back and forth between the machines as needed using one keyboard. It can pair with up to three (3) devices while the mouse pairs with two (2) devices at a time.

Comment: How do you switch the mouse between computers? Do you really need to flip the mouse and switch the button every time you want to switch between computers? I was thinking of this combination myself (there's a newer version of the keyboard due to be launched next week and I would be more than happy to get it -- Logitech K780 - https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01GV6HP0E/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE, but I'm concerned about the mouse switching part).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The keyboard has three buttons along the top that are used to switch between paired devices. Just tap the appropriate key and it lights up indicating the device it is connected to. Works well between my iPad and Windows PC (Windows 10). This is only a keyboard so I can't speak to the mouse aspect. Keyboards pretty good though.

Comment: But so how do you switch mice between machines? I understand the part about the keyboard switching and that's great!

Comment: I only use the keyboard. Not the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

- Insert a Bluetooth adapter into your computer's USB port. You do not need to do this if your computer already has built-in Bluetooth support.
- Turn on your Bluetooth mouse.
- Go to one of your computers, click the "Start" menu and click "Control Panel."
- Type "Bluetooth" in the top search bar.
- Click "Change Bluetooth Settings" and go to the "Options" tab.
- Check the boxes next to "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer,"
- Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer" and "Alert me when a new Bluetooth device wants to connect." This enables discovery mode, which allows your computer to find your Bluetooth mouse.
- Click "Add Bluetooth Device" in Control Panel. Select your mouse and click "Next."
- Choose a pairing method to use with your mouse. You can select "Create a pairing code for me" to have Windows generate an eight-digit key to enter when pairing the device, "Enter the Devices pairing code" if the mouse already has a code or "Pair Without a Code" to not use a pairing code for the mouse.
- Click "Next." Follow the instructions. During the process, Windows exchanges the pairing codes, and installs the drivers for the mouse. Click "Close" when this process is completed.

Repeat this process for any other computer that you would like to use the mouse with. You can now use the mouse with any of them.

Comment: The problem is selecting which computer receives the mouse input.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely dependent on the Bluetooth peripheral whether it allows pairing with more than one computer. This is commonly supported by, for example, Bluetooth headsets (I have one which pairs with up to 2 devices), but I haven't heard whether any mice do.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech has a couple of solutions for this, but it wouldn't work with your orochi. Another person answered about the ultrathin mouse they have that will allow switching between two computers. Another solution is that they have some of their bluetooth devices which include a dual purpose dongle. The dongle will do the bluetooth pairing for you to the keyboard/mouse as soon as the dongle is powered up. Thus the keyboard and mouse can be linked either using this default pairing or you can use those bluetooth devices on the same or other computers pairing directly with bluetooth. (the MX5500 desktop is one that does this)

The problem with this is, that it does require repairing on a second machine if you are using bluetooth only to connect any time you switch. However, the idea of pairing to the dongle rather than the PC means that you can just move the dongle to the second machine. When paired to the dongle, the keyboard/mouse just look like any other usb based keyboard and mouse as the dongle handles all the bluetooth dirtywork. (this is especially nice if you need keyboard/mouse access at boot-up)

I suppose if you were creative with a soldering iron you could probably buy a bluetooth receiver and drop an arduino nano in behind it and create your own dongle to do this with any device, but good luck on that one! To my knowledge, there isn't anyone out there doing it yet. Maybe there's a business idea for someone.

As a side note, IoGear also has a line of 'multi-link' devices that allow switching between up to 6 paired profiles. But thus far, they only include keyboards. However, one keyboard does have a touchpad on the side. Not much good for gaming, but useful for controlling a multi-head arrangement or pairing to your cell phone and tablet devices.

Of course, the best way to be able to use the orochi on both systems without pairing is to buy a second orochi.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to achieve this, there are two ways to get it done.

1. Buying a Bluetooth mouse that allows multiple device pairing, this isn't new as diverse audio devices allow it, so they would detect and pair immediately with diff devices such as phones, computers and tablets, having a limit of 2, 3, 5 etc depending on the company that makes them.
2. What I did :), I'm using a simple script (batch file). I use Bluetooth Command line tools available here: https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools, this allows 53:12:123:124 etc, using names is slower, addresses faster. So, in simple terms, I have my BT mouse paired with my laptop, I just close it / sleep, etc, and then run my script on my other computer while also pressing the pair button on the mouse, this will connect it to the other computer without manually removing/adding. Same thing applies back to my main laptop. It's easier and faster.

It's as simple as this:

```
btpair -u -b"34:88:5D:52:B0:B9"
btcom -c -b"34:88:5D:52:B0:B9" -c -s1124
```

The first line removes the mouse, the second line pairs it. The first data (34:88:etc) it's MY BT Mouse physical address, the 1124 is the standard identifier for BT mouse services (so, just change to fit your BT address), you can find what that is checking on device manager, or using the btdiscovery online tool provided with the package mentioned above). The script must have both lines, as you must remove it and add it again.

Works perfectly on my side. I found the how-to here on super user as other people were asking how to connect/disconnect/pair/unpair, then I just created my script. This, by MarcinJ was greatly useful [Scripting connecting/disconnecting a paired Bluetooth device](https://superuser.com/questions/1426949/scripting-connecting-disconnecting-a-paired-bluetooth-device/1427536#1427536)