# Connecting/Disconnecting to Bluetooth Device via CMD, PS, or AHK?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, bluetooth, autohotkey

I'm at my wits' end right now.

I'm on the latest version of Windows 10 and I just want to run a script to connect/disconnect to my Bluetooth headphones when executed. I've looked at a couple other posts on the website, [namely this one,](https://superuser.com/a/1427536) which all suggested to [use this](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/). I actually had it working for a while for about an hour, however, it suddenly starting throwing up System Error 87 after a while (and I hadn't changed anything, it just stopped working).

Are there any alternative ways to accomplish this or will I just be stuck having to click three extra buttons?

Comment: Have you figured this out, possibly with AHK? I simply want to turn on bluetooth with AHK...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: *(You'll need Administrative Privilege)*

> ```
> $device = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq "Bluetooth" -and $_.FriendlyName -eq "FriendlyDeviceName"}
> Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
> Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
> Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId >$device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
> ```

***NOTE: THIS SCRIPT ISN'T MINE, I TOOK IT FROM [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648715/8479597).***

Additionally, you can use these tools:
http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and [it looks like](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/quickly-connect-paired-bluetooth-devices-windows-10/) there's already a shortcut for it:

**<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then click *Connect***

[image: Keying the shortcut and clicking connect and choosing my headphones; then they connect.]

However, one could abbreviate it further by creating a tricky [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to make it all happen with one keystroke.

```
#SingleInstance, force
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen


^!c:: ; Press Ctrl + Alt + C to start

; You'll need to find your Connect button's Screen coordinates with Window Spy. 
connectButtonX = 1120
connectButtonY = 570

; You'll need to find your device entry's Screen coordinates with Window Spy.
deviceEntryX = 1130
deviceEntryY = 240

Send #a ;Win + A

WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Shellexperiencehost.exe,, 5
If ErrorLevel
 Return
Sleep, 500
Click %connectButtonX%, %connectButtonY%

WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Shellexperiencehost.exe,, 5
If ErrorLevel
 Return
Sleep, 1200
Click %deviceEntryX%, %deviceEntryY%

Send {Escape}
```

Comment: Ugh.  As some who has used AHK for other purposes, I would hope that a better way can be done than hard-coding to a specific screen resolution.  And making this and then holding Ctrl-Alt-C seems more convoluted than holding the Start button and pressing K, which I think is just going to be a fastr way for you.  If you want to support a situation without a Start button on a keyboard (maybe for remote connections), maybe AHK can simulate holding down the start button and pressking K.

Comment: (To clarify, I'm suggesting that Win+k is simpler than Win+a and then Connect.  I'm not suggesting that removes the need to then click on something that represents the individual device.)

Comment: I wasn't aware that Win+k went right to the connect screen.